# How to determine induction generator poles?

Tags: generator, induction

I designed an induction generator in the Maxwell program for a wind turbine, and it worked. I selected 4 poles for stator and rotor and 12 slots for both.

Is the number of poles enough for 1500 RPM speed and the number of slots (for salient poles machine)?

Could you draw on the figure and show where the poles are?

[image]

Comment: The number of poles do not affect the speed of a wind generator; it's the wind that does this.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronous speed RPM = 120 X frequency / poles. With 4 poles and 1500 RPM, you get 50 Hz.

For a 3-phase motor, you would distribute three sets of phase windings in the stator slots to make a pole. There are various schemes for distributing and overlapping the windings to do that.

For a squirrel-cage rotor, the slots are filled with cast aluminum or copper bars and the ends are connected to copper or aluminum rings at each end. For a wound rotor, the windings are distributed similarly to the stator.